# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.gwt.util.tools.Utility.versionCompare - Google Web Toolkit SDK 2.6.0

Tags: java, gwt, eclipse-plugin

My project using gwt maven plugin 2.5.1 and gwt 2.5.1. My Eclipse IDE have installed Google Web Toolkit SDK 2.6.0.

[image]
When i debug my project with Super Dev Mode  i get error

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.gwt.util.tools.Utility.versionCompare

I have checked the error. This error is caused by class `int enum com.google.gwt.dev.util.arg.SourceLevel` , this class have bellow line code make error:

```
 if (Utility.versionCompare(javaVersionString, sourceLevels[i].stringValue) >= 0) {
```

class `com.google.gwt.util.tools.Utility` in file `gwt-dev-2.5.1-sources.jar` has no method `Utility.versionCompare`. I have tried upgrade gwt to upper version but make huge conflict với another library in my project.
My question is: how to run  Google Web Toolkit SDK 2.6.0 with project GWT-2.5.1  ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is a Maven project, then M2Eclipse and the Google Plugin for Eclipse should auto-configure the project to use the GWT referenced from your POM, and not the one you could have installed in your Eclipse.

So the problem is that you have GWT 2.6 on the classpath; your project is misconfigured. Try re-importing it; you should **not** have a GWT *library* in your dependencies, as GWT JARs should appear in the "Maven Dependencies" *library*.

If you always use Maven for your projects, then you can uninstall the GWT SDK that's bundled as an Eclipse plugin (as shown in your screenshot).

Comment: Thank! my project is using Maven. I have checked the Java Build Path and there are two gwt-dev.jar ( gwt-dev-2.5.0.jar(in Maven Dependence)  and  gwt-dev-2.6.0.jar (of plugin)) in JavaPath . Sorry I forget mention about Maven in my question.